# Group by with order by condition without using multiple sql sentence

Tags: mysql, sql, logic

Table structure

```
 id
 user_id_1
 user_id_2
 message
 create_date
```

Sample data

```
 1 - 1 - 2 - "lorem ipsum" - 05.20.2016 15:12:11
 2 - 2 - 1 - "lorem ipsum dolor" - 05.20.2016 15:12:12
 3 - 3 - 1 - "lorem ipsum dolor sit" - 05.20.2016 15:12:13
 4 - 1 - 2 - "lorem ipsum dolor sit amet" - 05.20.2016 15:12:14
```

I have a table for messaging. And I want to list message list of user (id:1). I'm using sql sentence at below.

```
SELECT * FROM messages 
WHERE (`user_id_1` = 1 OR `user_id_2` = 1)
GROUP BY IF(`user_id_1`=1,`user_id_2`,`user_id_1`)
ORDER BY create_date DESC
```

With using group by I can get every user just once, but the problem is `GROUP BY` using the first row. Like, for `user_id_1: 1` I want to get `id:4` but its showing `id:1`.

Summary: The task is, listing conversations of user with last message. Is there any way to do that with just one SQL sentence, without using `"SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM ... ORDER BY) GROUP BY"` way.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *`.  That is a SQL anti-pattern and is not supported by most databases.

Instead, use filtering to get the rows that you want.  Here is one method:

```
select m.*
from messages m
where 1 in (m.user_id_1, m.user_id_2) and
      m.create_date = (select max(m2.create_date)
                       from messages m2
                       where m2.user_id_1 = m.user_id2 or
                             m2.user_id_2 = m.user_id1
                      );
```